# Python's re library's sub method "eating" capturing groups

Tags: python, regex

### Introductory gibberish:

My current project is sort of a Lisp Parser, and RegEx is a true wonder, though it's giving me a little headache in this particular function:

## What the function should do:

Receive a string containing an equation and return it formatted so that the parser can actually read it (for the moment, it means inserting multiplication marks between variables, braces, and numbers

## What it actually does:

The function succeeds in finding the spots to replace, but, somewhere in the assembly of the returned string, it seems to lose the original matching pattern in the `\1` slot and squeeze an ~unidentified char~ character in there (the square, represented by `[]`, since I couldn't manage to paste it here).

**Any insights on why this happens?**

---

### Code:

```
import re

def eqxFormat(eq):
    vars = "x"
    for i in vars:
        eq = re.sub(r'%s([0-9\(])' % i, '%s*\1' %i, eq)
        eq = re.sub(r'([0-9\)])%s' % i, '\1*%s' %i, eq)

    eq = re.sub(r'([0-9])\(', r'\1*(', eq)
    eq = re.sub(r'\)([0-9])', r')*\1', eq)
    return eq

eq = "3(x+2(5-x))^3+2x^2+x(x^-1*exp(x))"

print(eqxFormat(eq))
```

### Output:

```
3*(x+2*(5-x))^3+[]*x^2+x*[]x^-1*exp(x))
```

Comment: You wrote a lot of text :) Can you just give the input, the expected output and the actual output?

Comment: I'll try to be more concise from now on :)
Padraic just answered my question, but thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use raw string `r` when you reference the capture group  `r'%s*\1'` and  `r'\1*%s'`:

```
  eq = re.sub(r'%s([0-9\(])' % i, r'%s*\1' %i, eq)
  eq = re.sub(r'([0-9\)])%s' % i, r'\1*%s' %i, eq)
```

Once you add the `r` your code will output the correct string:

```
In [6]: eq = "3(x+2(5-x))^3+2x^2+x(x^-1*exp(x))"

In [7]: eqxFormat(eq)
Out[7]: '3*(x+2*(5-x))^3+2*x^2+x*(x^-1*exp(x))'
```

You could also escape the backslash with another i.e `'%s*\\1'`, if you don't use a raw string or escape you get `Ctrl-A`:

```
In [8]: "\1"
Out[8]: '\x01'
In [1]: r"\1"
Out[1]: '\\1'
```

Comment: Works like a charm!
Thanks a lot!